Change a view in a tab of tab bar controller
i have an ios app with 3 tab bars but multiple views. I am trying to change the view of one tab bar depending on the user sign in status. Basically if the user is signed-in i want that tab to show a profile view but if the user is not signed-in i want the tab to show a sign-in view. The remaining two tabs won't be changed during this process.
I have been able to do this with my code but the problem i'm having is when the login screen is presented and the user successfully signs in, it doesn't automatically switch to the profile tab. Right now i will have to close the app and rerun for the profile screen to show. i want the login screen to be immediately replaced by the profile tab on successful sign in.
I am also looking to change that tab from profile view immediately to a login view if the user clicks the sign out button.
This is my code for both the login view controller and the tab bar controller.
LOGIN VC
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
        var mainTabBarController: NewMainTabBarController?
    
    //MARK: - IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    
    //MARK: - View Life Cycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        signInButton.style = .wide
        
        signInButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    //MARK: - IB Actions
    
    @IBAction func forgotPasswordButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        forgotPassword()
    }
    
    @IBAction func emailSignInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        emailSignIn()
    }
    
    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func googleSignInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("sign in button tapped")
        setupSignIn()
    }
    

    
    //MARK: - Email Sign in
    
    func emailSignIn() {
        
        if emailTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {

            ProgressHUD.show()
            
            MyUser.loginUserWith(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (error, isEmailVerified) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else if isEmailVerified {
                    
                    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.mainTabBarController?.updateUserStatus()
                    
                } else {
                    ProgressHUD.showError("Please verify your email!")
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("All fields are required!")
        }
    }
    
    func forgotPassword(){
        
        if emailTextField.text != "" {

            MyUser.resetPassword(email: emailTextField.text!) { (error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Please check your email!")
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("Please insert your email address.")
        }
    }
  //MARK: - Google Sign in
    
    func setupSignIn(){
        
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
        
        let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: self) { [unowned self] result, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                // ...
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user,
                  let idToken = user.idToken?.tokenString
            else {
                print("Failed to retrieve authentication data")
                return
            }
            
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                           accessToken: user.accessToken.tokenString)
            
            // ...
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Firebase aut Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                } 
                
                //i added this else lines to add the user to firestore
                else {
                    FirebaseListener.shared.downloadCurrentUserFromFirebase(userId: result!.user.uid, email: "email")
                }
                
                if result?.user != nil {
                    
                    let user = MyUser(_objectId: result!.user.uid,_fullname: "", _email: "", _phone: 0)
                    
                    user.saveUserLocally()
                }
                
                // At this point, our user is signed in
                print("user is signed in")
                self.mainTabBarController?.updateUserStatus()
               
            }
            
        }
    }
}

**TAB BAR CONTROLLER VC**
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

protocol NewMainTabBarControllerProtocol: AnyObject {
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController]? { get set }
    func updateUserStatus()
    func switchToProfileScreen()
}

class NewMainTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, NewMainTabBarControllerProtocol {
    
    let profileViewControllerIndex = 2
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        setupTabBar()
        updateUserStatus()
    }
    
    func updateUserStatus() {
        if MyUser.currentUser() == nil {
            print("User is not present")
            showLoginScreen()
        } else {
            showProfileScreen()
        }
    }
    
    func switchToProfileScreen() {
        selectedIndex = profileViewControllerIndex
    }
    
    private func showLoginScreen() {
        guard let loginViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") else {
            fatalError("Failed to instantiate LoginViewController from storyboard.")
        }
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        navController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Login", image: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), selectedImage: nil)
        viewControllers?[profileViewControllerIndex] = navController
    }
    
//    private 
    func showProfileScreen() {
        guard let profileViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") else {
            fatalError("Failed to instantiate ProfileViewController from storyboard.")
        }
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileViewController)
        navController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(systemName: "gear"), selectedImage: nil)
        viewControllers?[profileViewControllerIndex] = navController
    }
    
    private func setupTabBar() {
        let uploadViewController = UIViewController()
        uploadViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let uploadNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: uploadViewController)
        uploadNavController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Upload", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), selectedImage: nil)
        
        let exploreViewController = UIViewController()
        exploreViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let exploreNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: exploreViewController)
        exploreNavController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Explore", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), selectedImage: nil)
        
        let profileViewController = UIViewController()
        profileViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let profileNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileViewController)
        profileNavController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Placeholder", image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), selectedImage: nil)
        
        viewControllers = [uploadNavController, exploreNavController, profileNavController]
    }
}

